# Reuse matched pattern in inserted or appended line with GNU sed

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed, text-processing

I am trying to insert (resp. append) a line before (resp. after) a pattern with sed.

Maybe awk would be simpler but I am not familiar with it.
Here is the input

```
bar

wow

hee
```

And the wanted output :

```
bar
something
foobar

wow
something
foowow

hee
something
foohee
```

I tried the following with GNU sed :

```
sed '/^\(bar\|wow\|hee\)/a something\nfoo\1' input
```

But it printed `1` instead of the matched pattern.
Actually, I'd like to print the whole line that begins with `bar|wow|hee`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed can do more than just search and replace: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

```
sed '/^\(bar\|wow\|hee\)/ {
  p
  i\something
  s/^/foo/
}' file
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the `p` for printing the matched line! It seems so obvious now x). Plus, nice substitution of line beginning to `foo` with `s/^/foo`, I would not have thought it worked!

Answer (score 4):

you can use replacing like:

```
sed 's/^\(bar\|wow\|hee\)/&\n something\nfoo&/' input
```

this will replace the founded pattern with it self and so.... and it self again.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did in the end but I was not satisfied with this solution. Although it works fine I do not think it is the most elegant for what I was doing was a bit more complicated (inserting lines before, appending lines after, i.e. something more like glenn jackman's answer). I voted your answer up since I tested it.

Answer (score 2):

awk to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^(bar|wow|hee)$/{print $0 RS "something" RS "foo" $0 RS}'
```

Comment: This does the job all right, however I am still not into the awk black magic instructions thing :) (but I recognize the power of awk)

Comment: compare with the `sed` solution.  Which one is easier to understand?  Here you just need to know that RS means record separator, which is new line by default.

Comment: And what is $0 : the matched pattern, or the line matching the pattern? In my case I had to remove your first $ sign indicating an end of line, because my pattern is just the beginning of a more complicated line, which I wanted to print entirely after 'foo'.

Comment: with the anchoring `/^ .. $/` it will correspond to the pattern, but it means the line. ($1, .. , $NF are the fields up to NF number of fields).

Comment: I feel awk is more suited to edit organized data (typically in columns) than code, and the inverse for sed, am I right?

Comment: Right, it parses the line based on field separator, Works great with structured data. I think A. W. and K. wanted to build a UNIX database tool out of awk but didn't proceed.